# Split array to sub-arrays 5 times while keeping unique pairs in all sub-arrays

Tags: python, algorithm

*Background: I'm a conference manager and during the meetings I need to split the participates a few times into groups. I though to use python but I'm struggling.*

I need to split 70 people into 10 groups of 7.
Also, I need to split them 5 times (5 rounds).
In each round I need that in each team, there won't be a pair that was together in the same team in all the rounds before that.

Let's say the people are an array `[0,1,...,69]` and splitting to groups is actually creating sub-arrays in equal size of 7.

A good output would be (example for 2 completely unique rounds and missing 3 rounds):

```
Round 1:
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48], [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62], [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]]

Round 2:
[[0, 9, 18, 27, 35, 44, 53, 62], [1, 10, 19, 36, 45, 54], [2, 11, 20, 28, 37, 46, 55, 63], [3, 12, 29, 38, 47, 64], [4, 13, 21, 30, 39, 48, 56, 65], [5, 22, 31, 40, 57, 66], [6, 14, 23, 32, 41, 49, 58, 67], [15, 24, 33, 50, 59, 68], [7, 16, 25, 34, 42, 51, 60, 69], [8, 17, 26, 43, 52, 61]]

Round 3:
...

Round 4:
...

Round 5:
...
```

Any help please?
I though this would be an easy task in python but I can't get it right for hours now. I would appreciate python code but any other language that I can easily compile and run it great too.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to search for a pairing / scheduling algorithm; I've changed your tags to get help from that group.  "easy task in Python" presumes that this is an "easy task" in the first place -- this is not.  You have 2415 pairings to cluster in ten `cliques` of 21 for each of 5 "rounds".

Comment: You require that the cliques being mutually exclusive and exhaustive for five rounds; I'm trying to convince myself whether this is even possible.  Each round gives you 105 pairings that cannot be repeated in any later round; are you *sure* that you can continually construct 10 lists of 7 people who have *never* worked together?
This requires a set of projective plains **O(70, 7)** with a "side requirement" of having mutually exclusive and exhaustive lines among the planes.

Comment: Maybe first round is stride = 1, second round is stride = 7, third round is stride = 15, 4th round is stride = 31, etc.

Comment: @Prune Isn't it 210 pairings each round? (21 * 10)

Comment: Yes, 210.  [headslap]  I divided by 2 *twice* in my head.

Comment: This isn't a simple problem.

Instead of requiring zero collisions, think about it as an optimization problem: what is the minimum number of collisions (repeated pairings) given n people organized into m groups repeated k times? There are definitely cases where you can't get zero collisions.

I don't have a complete/correct greedy algorithm off the top of my head, but I can certainly think of heuristics to minimize the number of repeated pairings that can be computed within feasible constraints.

Comment: @Todd I wondered what the actual problem was. Thanks for the heads up. The problem is also known as [Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem). FWIW, the problem is easily solved with 77 people arranged in 11 groups of 7 for 5 rounds. The best I could do with 70 people, 10 groups, 5 rounds is 1048 unique pairs, leaving one duplicated pair. It would be interesting to know if that's actually the best that can be done.

Comment: Update: my genetic algorithm finally got around to finding the answer. So the problem with 70 people, 10 groups, 5 rounds *is* solvable.

Comment: Yeah let's see that thing =) @user3386109

Comment: I cannot express how much I appreciate your help! Many thanks. Also, because you mentioned the problem's name I found this nice [online near-solver](https://goodenoughgolfers.com) for future reference and easy use.

Comment: The code I've come up with is better than a "near" solver =) it actually solves these problems with some consistency. Let it run for at most a minute and it spits out the groupings fairly rapidly.

Comment: Yeah I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This same approach runs much faster in Rust - full project files and binaries available [here](https://github.com/ttappr/socialx).

By the way, this problem is known by a lot of different names, one is the "Social Golf Problem". The original problem was published in some esoteric periodical from 1850, and called "Kirkland's Schoolgirl Problem". Combinatorics is an interesting domain of problems.

I've played around some more with a solution to this interesting problem, and came back to update this post. The code below is the primary piece of code that does groupings.

The participant objects each maintain a list of their 'acquaintances' which helps determine if they can join a group or not, among other things. The program can solve the problem anywhere from instantly to a minute or two. On average, it's just under 5 seconds (I have an old system). Running it on Pypy3 it's much faster.

This piece of code creates groupings for one round. It gets called 5 (or whatever the parameters specify) times per conference attempt.

```
def run_round(round_id, participants, groups):
    RAND_CANDIDATE_BIAS  = 4
    num_regroup_attempts = len(participants) * 2
    num_rand_candidates  = groups[0].size

    for participant in participants:
        found = False
        random.shuffle(groups)

        # First attempt to find a group.
        for group in groups:
            if try_join(participant, group):
                found = True
                break

        # If not successful, see if getting other participants (regroup 
        # candidates) to change groups will create an opening for the 
        # participant.
        if not found:
            for _ in range(num_regroup_attempts):
                if not random.randint(0, RAND_CANDIDATE_BIAS):
                    # Grouped acquaintances will try to regroup.
                    acqs       = participant.acquaintances
                    candidates = [a for a in acqs if a.group]
                else:
                    # Randomly selected participants will try to regroup.
                    candidates = random.choices(participants,
                                                k=num_rand_candidates)
                    candidates = [cand for cand in candidates if cand.group]

                random.shuffle(candidates)

                for regroup_candidate in candidates:
                    if change_group(regroup_candidate, groups):

                        # Candidate regrouped, see if there's an opening now.
                        if try_join_any(participant, groups):
                            found = True
                            break
                if found:
                    break

    return mixer.Round(round_id, groups)
```

Below is the output from the program. The first number of each row is the group number - it can be ignored.

```
Oo>>>>>> Sun Mar  8 20:53:12 2020 <<<<<<oO

Iteration 1 best so far: 1 groupless

[[[ Iteration 2 -- SOLVED!! ]]]

Conference(3,
    Round(1, [
        Group( 1, [ 1, 35, 41, 42, 44, 45, 57]),
        Group( 2, [ 2, 10, 37, 40, 43, 47, 55]),
        Group( 3, [ 3, 15, 31, 36, 62, 63, 68]),
        Group( 4, [ 4,  8, 20, 26, 29, 32, 54]),
        Group( 5, [ 5, 46, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69]),
        Group( 6, [ 6, 17, 22, 23, 27, 39, 53]),
        Group( 7, [ 7, 14, 21, 33, 48, 52, 60]),
        Group( 8, [ 9, 12, 25, 38, 49, 50, 70]),
        Group( 9, [11, 18, 19, 24, 34, 51, 59]),
        Group(10, [13, 16, 28, 30, 56, 58, 61]),
    ]),
    Round(2, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  5, 10, 15, 51, 52, 70]),
        Group( 2, [ 2, 11, 25, 44, 46, 61, 68]),
        Group( 3, [ 3,  8, 12, 27, 34, 43, 67]),
        Group( 4, [ 4, 39, 41, 48, 55, 58, 65]),
        Group( 5, [ 6, 26, 28, 50, 59, 63, 64]),
        Group( 6, [ 7, 23, 36, 38, 45, 56, 66]),
        Group( 7, [ 9, 14, 16, 20, 22, 37, 42]),
        Group( 8, [13, 18, 33, 35, 54, 62, 69]),
        Group( 9, [17, 21, 24, 29, 31, 47, 49]),
        Group(10, [19, 30, 32, 40, 53, 57, 60]),
    ]),
    Round(3, [
        Group( 1, [ 1, 18, 27, 32, 37, 56, 68]),
        Group( 2, [ 2, 30, 45, 48, 50, 51, 67]),
        Group( 3, [ 3,  5,  6, 29, 38, 44, 60]),
        Group( 4, [ 4,  9, 23, 24, 40, 46, 62]),
        Group( 5, [ 7, 13, 22, 49, 55, 57, 63]),
        Group( 6, [ 8, 10, 25, 31, 33, 41, 59]),
        Group( 7, [11, 12, 15, 20, 35, 58, 66]),
        Group( 8, [14, 17, 19, 54, 61, 64, 70]),
        Group( 9, [16, 21, 26, 36, 43, 53, 65]),
        Group(10, [28, 34, 39, 42, 47, 52, 69]),
    ]),
    Round(4, [
        Group( 1, [ 1, 14, 31, 34, 46, 50, 58]),
        Group( 2, [ 2,  4,  6, 18, 21, 57, 66]),
        Group( 3, [ 3, 23, 26, 51, 55, 61, 69]),
        Group( 4, [ 5,  9, 13, 17, 32, 36, 59]),
        Group( 5, [ 7, 15, 37, 41, 53, 54, 67]),
        Group( 6, [ 8, 11, 40, 42, 56, 65, 70]),
        Group( 7, [10, 20, 27, 28, 49, 60, 62]),
        Group( 8, [12, 24, 30, 33, 39, 44, 63]),
        Group( 9, [16, 19, 35, 38, 47, 48, 68]),
        Group(10, [22, 25, 29, 43, 45, 52, 64]),
    ]),
    Round(5, [
        Group( 1, [ 1, 39, 43, 59, 61, 62, 66]),
        Group( 2, [ 2, 24, 38, 42, 53, 58, 64]),
        Group( 3, [ 3, 11, 16, 32, 33, 45, 49]),
        Group( 4, [ 4, 22, 31, 35, 60, 67, 70]),
        Group( 5, [ 5, 18, 20, 23, 41, 47, 63]),
        Group( 6, [ 6, 30, 36, 46, 52, 54, 55]),
        Group( 7, [ 7, 12, 17, 28, 51, 65, 68]),
        Group( 8, [ 8, 19, 21, 37, 44, 50, 69]),
        Group( 9, [ 9, 10, 29, 34, 48, 56, 57]),
        Group(10, [13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27, 40]),
    ]))

Oo>>>>>> Sun Mar  8 20:53:13 2020 <<<<<<oO
```

There are more ways that this approach can be improved on. For instance, it could go back in time to earlier rounds and do participant group swaps to influence future/current openings for ungrouped members. Plus, a better algorithm for selecting regroup candidates and which groups they should swap to would be nice. Right now it's just random; based mostly on hunches.

Applied to the Kirkman's Schoolgirls problem.

```
Oo>>>>>>>>>>>>> Mon Mar  9 02:13:33 2020 <<<<<<<<<<<<<oO

Iteration 1 best so far: 7 groupless
Iteration 12 best so far: 6 groupless
Iteration 96 best so far: 5 groupless
Iteration 420 best so far: 4 groupless

[[[ Iteration 824 -- SOLVED!! ]]]

Conference(825,
    Round(1, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  5, 15]),
        Group( 2, [ 2, 10, 14]),
        Group( 3, [ 3,  4,  8]),
        Group( 4, [ 6,  9, 13]),
        Group( 5, [ 7, 11, 12]),
    ]),
    Round(2, [
        Group( 1, [ 1, 11, 14]),
        Group( 2, [ 2,  4, 15]),
        Group( 3, [ 3, 12, 13]),
        Group( 4, [ 5,  6, 10]),
        Group( 5, [ 7,  8,  9]),
    ]),
    Round(3, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  8, 13]),
        Group( 2, [ 2,  3, 11]),
        Group( 3, [ 4,  9, 10]),
        Group( 4, [ 5, 12, 14]),
        Group( 5, [ 6,  7, 15]),
    ]),
    Round(4, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  7, 10]),
        Group( 2, [ 2,  6, 12]),
        Group( 3, [ 3,  9, 14]),
        Group( 4, [ 4,  5, 13]),
        Group( 5, [ 8, 11, 15]),
    ]),
    Round(5, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  2,  9]),
        Group( 2, [ 3,  5,  7]),
        Group( 3, [ 4,  6, 11]),
        Group( 4, [ 8, 10, 12]),
        Group( 5, [13, 14, 15]),
    ]),
    Round(6, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  4, 12]),
        Group( 2, [ 2,  7, 13]),
        Group( 3, [ 3, 10, 15]),
        Group( 4, [ 5,  9, 11]),
        Group( 5, [ 6,  8, 14]),
    ]),
    Round(7, [
        Group( 1, [ 1,  3,  6]),
        Group( 2, [ 2,  5,  8]),
        Group( 3, [ 4,  7, 14]),
        Group( 4, [ 9, 12, 15]),
        Group( 5, [10, 11, 13]),
    ]))

Oo>>>>>>>>>>>>> Mon Mar  9 02:13:38 2020 <<<<<<<<<<<<<oO
```

> Fifteen young ladies in a school walk out three abreast for seven days
> in succession: it is required to arrange them daily so that no two
> shall walk twice abreast.

^^ Was the original combinatorics problem from 1850.

I find it interesting that solutions to that problem from 1850 focused on correlations to geometry to find possible groups.

The idea to go back in time to previous groupings and adjust them to make present groupings easier is something I did explore. It turned out to be simpler than the original description of the feature as I worded it. Moving participants around in previous rounds utilizes the exact same features used in placing participants in the current round; there aren't any "temporal" aspects of it. The rounds collectively are all part of one single larger grid.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what an answer looks like:

```
Round 1
  [ 0,11,18,50,56,60,63]
  [ 1,19,38,41,43,47,69]
  [ 2,27,37,55,57,65,66]
  [ 3,15,23,35,44,53,62]
  [ 4,21,28,34,49,61,67]
  [ 5,16,22,29,31,39,45]
  [ 6,10,14,20,24,25,46]
  [ 7,17,32,42,54,58,59]
  [ 8,12,13,26,30,36,52]
  [ 9,33,40,48,51,64,68]
Round 2
  [ 0,27,28,32,38,44,51]
  [ 1, 3,14,37,48,59,67]
  [ 2,24,34,45,47,50,68]
  [ 4,20,31,42,43,52,65]
  [ 5, 7,13,18,25,40,61]
  [ 6, 8,16,33,35,58,69]
  [ 9,22,26,41,53,60,66]
  [10,15,21,30,54,57,63]
  [11,17,19,23,36,39,64]
  [12,29,46,49,55,56,62]
Round 3
  [ 0, 8, 9,39,47,54,55]
  [ 1, 5,21,26,42,62,64]
  [ 2,10,11,33,44,52,67]
  [ 3,12,24,61,63,65,69]
  [ 4,19,22,25,51,56,57]
  [ 6,23,31,40,50,59,66]
  [ 7,16,28,37,46,53,68]
  [13,20,29,32,34,35,41]
  [14,17,18,27,30,43,45]
  [15,36,38,48,49,58,60]
Round 4
  [ 0,12,23,25,37,41,42]
  [ 1, 6,18,22,36,65,68]
  [ 2, 4,29,30,59,60,64]
  [ 3, 8,11,20,21,45,51]
  [ 5, 9,34,46,52,57,69]
  [ 7,15,19,24,26,27,31]
  [10,13,28,47,58,62,66]
  [14,32,33,39,49,50,53]
  [16,43,44,48,54,56,61]
  [17,35,38,40,55,63,67]
Round 5
  [ 0, 2, 3,13,22,43,46]
  [ 1,11,12,16,27,34,40]
  [ 4, 7,10,36,41,45,55]
  [ 5, 6,37,47,49,51,63]
  [ 8,15,25,32,64,66,67]
  [ 9,14,21,23,56,58,65]
  [17,31,33,57,60,61,62]
  [18,24,29,38,52,53,54]
  [19,28,30,35,42,48,50]
  [20,26,39,44,59,68,69]
```

And here's the C code I used as the fitness function for a genetic algorithm.

```
#define ROUNDS 5
#define GROUPS 10
#define PEOPLE 7
#define POPULATION (GROUPS * PEOPLE)

char pairs[POPULATION][POPULATION];
int choices[ROUNDS][GROUPS][PEOPLE];

int computeScore(void)
{
    memset(pairs, 0, sizeof(pairs));
    for (int round = 0; round < ROUNDS; round++)
        for (int group = 0; group < GROUPS; group++)
            for (int a = 0; a < (PEOPLE-1); a++)
                for (int b = a+1; b < PEOPLE; b++)
                {
                    int personA = choices[round][group][a];
                    int personB = choices[round][group][b];
                    pairs[personA][personB]++;
                    pairs[personB][personA]++;
                }

    int score = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < (POPULATION-1); a++)
        for (int b = a+1; b < POPULATION; b++)
            if (pairs[a][b] == 1)
                score++;
    return score;
}
```

The score is just the count of unique pairs. The target score is 1050 since `7C2 * 10 * 5 = 1050`.

---

BTW: Todd's method also works. Here's the answer with round 3 filled in:

```
Round 1
  [ 0,10,20,30,40,50,60]
  [ 1,11,21,31,41,51,61]
  [ 2,12,22,32,42,52,62]
  [ 3,13,23,33,43,53,63]
  [ 4,14,24,34,44,54,64]
  [ 5,15,25,35,45,55,65]
  [ 6,16,26,36,46,56,66]
  [ 7,17,27,37,47,57,67]
  [ 8,18,28,38,48,58,68]
  [ 9,19,29,39,49,59,69]
Round 2
  [ 0,19,28,37,46,55,64]
  [ 1,10,29,38,47,56,65]
  [ 2,11,20,39,48,57,66]
  [ 3,12,21,30,49,58,67]
  [ 4,13,22,31,40,59,68]
  [ 5,14,23,32,41,50,69]
  [ 6,15,24,33,42,51,60]
  [ 7,16,25,34,43,52,61]
  [ 8,17,26,35,44,53,62]
  [ 9,18,27,36,45,54,63]
Round 3
  [ 0,14,29,35,43,51,68]
  [ 1,15,20,36,44,52,69]
  [ 2,16,21,37,45,53,60]
  [ 3,17,22,38,46,54,61]
  [ 4,18,23,39,47,55,62]
  [ 5,19,24,30,48,56,63]
  [ 6,10,25,31,49,57,64]
  [ 7,11,26,32,40,58,65]
  [ 8,12,27,33,41,59,66]
  [ 9,13,28,34,42,50,67]
Round 4
  [ 0,17,25,39,41,58,63]
  [ 1,18,26,30,42,59,64]
  [ 2,19,27,31,43,50,65]
  [ 3,10,28,32,44,51,66]
  [ 4,11,29,33,45,52,67]
  [ 5,12,20,34,46,53,68]
  [ 6,13,21,35,47,54,69]
  [ 7,14,22,36,48,55,60]
  [ 8,15,23,37,49,56,61]
  [ 9,16,24,38,40,57,62]
Round 5
  [ 0,16,23,31,48,54,67]
  [ 1,17,24,32,49,55,68]
  [ 2,18,25,33,40,56,69]
  [ 3,19,26,34,41,57,60]
  [ 4,10,27,35,42,58,61]
  [ 5,11,28,36,43,59,62]
  [ 6,12,29,37,44,50,63]
  [ 7,13,20,38,45,51,64]
  [ 8,14,21,39,46,52,65]
  [ 9,15,22,30,47,53,66]
```

Comment: Very inspiring.

Comment: Great work @user3386109 verified your output. How much time does it take your code to reach an answer?

Comment: @Todd I was running the genetic algorithm for 10 minutes at a time. It took a few runs before getting lucky. The problem with a genetic algorithm is that it's very good at getting close to the answer, but is prone to getting stuck at a local maxima. The first (random) generation of solutions typically scores in the 700's. That improves to 1040 within seconds, but getting from 1040 to 1050 takes a lot of time, and some luck. OTOH, filling in round 3 for your solution is very fast. There are only 1 million possible answers, and it took about 20 seconds to try them all. 5 out of 1M work.

Comment: I bet if we combined both our strategies then we could probably generate the set of answers (or a large portion) for this problem quickly. @user3386109

Comment: @Todd That's true, after your code generates 4 valid rounds, my code can find the fifth. The thing I still don't understand is why your code fails on round 3, yet can generate rounds 4 and 5. Seems like it should be round 5 that fails, since the last round should be the most constrained.

Comment: I found that interesting as well. @user3386109

Comment: @user3386109 you could take a complete set of solution rounds and reorder the participants, then assign to groups using the same order of assignment and generate new tables.

Comment: @user3386109 what's a good source of information on genetic algorithms?

Comment: @Todd In response to reordering the participants: Yes, you are correct. The mapping from participants to numbers is totally arbitrary. So a single (numeric) solution can be rearranged 70! different ways from the point-of-view of the participants. Regarding GAs: I learned about genetic algorithms by reading articles in actual printed magazines a long time ago. So that's not much help to you. Searching for `[python] genetic algorithm` here on SO may be useful. There is, for example, a framework called [DEAP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deap/info) that I've seen mentioned (but haven't tried).

Comment: @user3386109 cool. Thanks for the tips. I was able to find some tutorial material. This is something I want to learn.